# How to add a button to html which will print my site to PDF?

Tags: internet-explorer, button, pdf-generation

I would like to add a button which will have the same functionality as going to "Settings->Print->Print to file". It should work for IE only.

To be more specific, this button should be show on my website and should automatically redirect to me "Printing" window where I can choose whether print to file or not. Even better if it can choose the proper "printer" and generate pdf.

Thanks for help.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

So you want this button to appear only in Internet Explorer and this has to print the page or generate the page to PDF?

Maybe you could try something like this in your head:

```html
<style>
  a.print { 
     display: none; 
  }
</style>

<!--[if IE]>
 <style>
      a.print {
        display: block;
      }
     </style>
<![endif]-->
```

And your buttons should be like:

```html
<a class="print" href="javascript:window.print()">Print</a>
```

Comment: Yeah, something like that. I already have a button which redirect me to print to PDF, but this button is shown on my pdf document. How can i hide it after clicking it on website?

Comment: Hi, by setting css for printmedia like so:

@media print {
   a.print { display: none; }
}

Comment: could you explain how does media print works? I ve never used it.

Comment: Ok, i have manage to do it with media print. (I read about it ;))

Comment: Thany you guys for your help.

Comment: No problem. I'm glad you figured it out!